# Why is PHP trying to write a file for an in memory sqlite database (and where is it?)

Tags: php, sqlite, memory

When I try to create a sqlite in memory database that is shared, it complains that it can't open the database file on my docker image (`circleci/php:7.2-fpm-node-browsers-legacy`) - yet it works just fine on my host machine...

```
php > $a = new Pdo('sqlite::memory:?cache=shared');

Warning: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 php shell code(1): PDO->__construct('sqlite::memory:...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1

php > $b = new Pdo('sqlite::memory:');
php >
```

One assumes that the sqlite driver is indeed trying to write a file and it's just not allowed to, but where is this file it's trying to write?

Useful reading: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Can you cite any documentation for `?cache=shared`? I'm not finding anything about it.

Comment: I did under "Useful reading" It turns out that although I got this message running docker locally, it didn't ocur in circleCI where I was actually wanting to run the tests, so for me the problem is solved but not answered so I'm not going to mark this as answere just yet.

Comment: That "useful reading" doesn't mention that specific syntax *for PDO*. And the PDO documentation doesn't either. So… ‍♂️

Comment: That tries to open a file named ":memory:?cache=shared" in the current working directory of the php process. That's presumably a directory the process doesn't have write permission for. Re-read the documentation you linked for the correct syntax for creating a shared-cache in-memory database (It might not be possible in PHP PDO, btw).